# SearchIndexer crashing repeatedly; Crashdump attached

Tags: crash, windows-search, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a brand new server (2012 R2) we built and setup Windows Search to index two folders.  We're stuck with Windows Search because of the integration with Windows, so another app isn't an option.

When it crashes, it corrupts the database (Or crashes because of corruption) and then starts all over again.  Sometimes it won't crash for a day or two, other times it crashes a few times a day.

Crashdump here.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17520956/DTS/MillCrashDump/SearchIndexer.exe.15636.zip

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Asked the same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1104326/my-searchindexer-exe-crashes-everyday It remained a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the dmp with Windg, shows the following callstack:

```
00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
03 kernel32!WerpReportFault
04 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter
05 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0
06 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
07 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
08 ntdll!RtlDispatchException
09 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0a msvcrt!memcpy
0b tquery!CRcovStrmTrans::Read
0c tquery!CRcovStrmIter::GetRec
0d tquery!CSdidLookupTable::LookupSDIDOrAdd
0e tquery!CSecurityStoreWrapper::LookupSDID
0f mssrch!CPluginCollectionSink::PushProperties
10 mssrch!CRobotThread::Thread
11 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
12 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

Crash happens at `msvcrt!memcpy`:

```
INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_msvcrt.dll!memcpy
```

Before this call you see a lockup of a security ID.

The last file Indexer access is `file:E:/[9a6f27d7-402a-4796-a80f-8e846f4eb36b]/Shared Files/Library/Pictures of Product/72- Series Photos/72-3170023.jpg`.

So look at the security settings of the file folder and make sure SYSTEM was read access. Also try to exclude that folder from search indexer.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the dump.  System has full access to all folders we're indexing - just verified that folder and parent folders.  I did remove it from the indexing just now.  We'll see what it does.  Thanks.

Comment: Still crashing after excluding that folder.  Latest dump here - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17520956/DTS/MillCrashDump/SearchIndexer.exe.20672.zip

Comment: same stack. this time crash at file **file:E:/[9a6f27d7-402a-4796-a80f-8e846f4eb36b]/UserShares/NParadis/My Documents/PDF files/Autosave/**. I have no idea how to fix this. try to rebuild Search index via control panel item

Comment: I also see that indexer has issues with password protected PDFs (HRESULT : 0x8004170b - FILTER_E_PASSWORD). try to remove all PDFs from indexer

Comment: Removing PDFs might work for troubleshooting, but the client would shoot us if that were the solution unfortunately.  Search index is rebuilt every time it crashes, so no love there.  Might be opening a ticket with Microsoft next since there is NOTHING on the net about this.

Comment: yes, do this and phone MS support. this is out of my scope/skills to fix this issue.